# Multicollinearity if independent variables sum to one?

Tags: time-series, least-squares, multicollinearity, ratio

I am intending to explain the variation in dependent variable Y through a number of ratios that, combined, sum to 1 in each period `t`

Hence, 
$$
Y_t = \alpha + \beta_i^I * X_t + \epsilon_t
$$
Where $X_t$ is a vector of ratios that sum to 1 (say 1/3, 1/6 and 3/6 in t = 1) and $\beta_i^I$ a vector of its beta coefficients. In actually, the ratios reflect the composition of a fund, that changes over time.

Is there multicollinearity if I include all the ratios? That is, should one of the ratios be excluded from the model (such as with the dummy variable trap) to avoid multicollinearity?

Since the ratios change disproportionally to each other but proportionally to the sum of 1, I'm not sure if this should be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multicollinearity arises when a variable $X_0$ can be written as a sum $\sum_{i=1}{\lambda_i X_i+\lambda_0+\epsilon}$, where perfect multicollinearity corresponds to the case where $\epsilon = 0$.

As I'm understanding your presentation, you have a number of variables $(X_1,X_2...X_i)$ with the property that $0 \leq X_j \leq 1$ and $\sum^i_{j=1}X_i =1$. As such, any one variable can be perfectly predicted given the state of the others - they are *perfectly* collinear!

Comment: So, one of the variables would have to be excluded from the regression, as in the solution to the dummy variable trap. The interpretation of the beta coefficients would then also be relative to the excluded variable. That is, if $X_i$ is excluded, $\beta_1$ measures the change in $Y$ based on a 1 percentage point change in $X_1$ relative to $X_i$. Correct?

Comment: So how does one proceed?